# Facebook - Possible to post on friends wall silently?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Through a web app, once the user has logged in through their facebook after giving the necessary permissions, would it be possible for a web app to:

1. select a random friend from the user's friends list (i'm assuming yes)
2. post on that friends's wall from the user's account silently. This would all be done in the background and the user would have no idea regarding whose wall the message was sent to. The user would only get a feedback saying - "post sent to a random friend"

Do you think its possible through facebook api?

Comment: What would you like do with that, exactly ?
I mean, if you could not notify the user, he probably will not see the post on his timeline, and friends dont use to check everybody timeline's every day, so you would flood a lot of people timeline with same thing? ANd didnt get what you really are trying to do ... 
Facebook Api is a very complex thing, and its not for automation and free marketing, the API must be used and was created for allow us to create new features for the website .

Answer (score 4):

Of course that´s not possible. You can´t post to the wall of a friend with the API, you can´t even get a list of all friends anymore. You can only get a list of friend who authorized your App. Also, the message must be user generated and autoposting is not allowed in general.

Comment: Thank you! my friend wanted to consult me about his 'great' idea. I thought it won't be possible, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Nice answer, i would like to add that the correct way is to send a request for user to invite him for using the app, before you think about any kind of API call, you need make user friends install the app. After user install the app, your use wil be able to list their friends, but still not possible to post on any user timeline anymore, that was possible in the past, but had a very very bad use. But the problem persists, because this kind of spam is done by some kind of WIndows software that logs in user accounts, and do every kind of spam without API. Thats a big problem .

Comment: I also would like to add that if your idea was about doing that RANDOM POST at some Event, Page that user manages, or Pages that user likes, it is possible, but is not a correct thing to do with your users, and +luschn sayd, content MUST be user filled, and the actions can not be performed without user interaction .. So your friend could learn more about platform, so his ideas will follow the platform standards, and keep at your mind that spam is very bad for the platform, for the users and also for your braand :)

Comment: I completely agree with you @DavidAugustus. I think ethically it is so wrong. However, what they wanted was kind of a game that had the ability to make a random post to a friend. Then you'd get a reward since its risky as you don't know who'd that go to. Then that friend would post to another and so on. In the process, helping advertise the brand.

Comment: getting a reward for it would even be worse. you are not even allowed to reward users for posting on their own wall - for very good reasons.

Comment: "helping advertise the brand" is nothing else than "spamming" in that case ;)

Comment: LoL!! Ok. But you still can trigger an invite or request dialog for a random friend, but once you can list only friends that are using app, you must engadge them into the game first. The correct experience for rewarding users is: User asks another user for help... Then other users use the app to receive and send the reward, that must be received by the user who asked by ... When he does receive he can send back also. I have all this ready for implementation .. Instead of POSTING into user timelines, today Facebook uses Open Graph Actions that now can be easly implemented using FB.UI .

Comment: This is not about "advertising", this is about social game experience. You should think about spend some money on Facebook Ads and content marketing instead of thinking on flooding all users timelines .